# rewrite url multiple times? multiple tables with urls

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting

(i've asked a similar question earlier, but this is a more specific question, thats why i start a new thread.)

I am at the beginning of a asp.net project where i maybe will use url rewriter. (for the first time)

I have a couple of users who have individual subdomains.. and in every subdomain each user has individually categories, sub categories and pages. so for example, a users webpage could look like:

```
user1.mydomain.com/category1/sub1/page1
user1.mydomain.com/category1/sub2/page45
user1.mydomain.com/category1/page123
user1.mydomain.com/category2/sub56/page134
```

as you understand these categoris and pages are dynamic, and i want to use url rewrite.
But due to large amount of users, i dont want one HUGE list of urlrewrites.

So my question is.

Is it possible to rewrite the URL multiple times?
first the web application check for the subdomain, which gives us some ID for the wep page.

```
user1.mydomain.com/category1/page1.aspx -> users.mydomain.com/category1/page1.aspx?accountID=1
```

and then depending on the, in this case, accountID checks for the correct "lookup table for url rewrites"

something like:

```
account1_url_list
account2_url_list
...
```

To get the correct url for the rest of the "pretty-url", in this case "/category1"

i guess that the web.config file cant handle so many url-rewrites?

And one other question.

What happens with urlrewrite when one of the users points his own domain to his page at my web application?
So that the adress bar in internet explorer, or firefox is something like:

```
www.user.com points at user1.mydomain.com
```

am I able to get the correct ID of that user?

Thanks! 
Matte

---

Thanks for the reply.
Unfortionally i am not able to run a url rewrite on the IIS, i think. Only some kind o .net rewriter like 
www.urlrewriting.net

I have a question regarding someone pointing his own domainname to my web application.
Is it possible to use the ”user1.”, ”user2” sub domain names to match the user to his account, or do I also have to use his domainname during the process to find his accountID?

```
Lets say user1 owns a domainname. www.user1domain.com
he points that domain to user1.mydomain.com
so the visible url is www.user1domain.com.
```

What happens?

Is there some command to find what subdomain his domain is pointing to?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of IIS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, URL Rewriter supports multiple processing steps, as Eok discusses in his blog entry regarding the processing chain and continuing or stopping processing:  http://blogs.iis.net/eokim/archive/2008/06/05/url-rewrite-module-basic-understanding-lt-rule-gt.aspx

The web.config can handle a very large number or rewrite rules (I don't actually know how many, but it might be fun to test!).

If you've got more than say a couple dozen rules you might have a problem that could be refactored and simplified.